# Javascript Assigning a new variable inside an array while looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

//I am trying to make every element in the array colors get assigned a different color, but when I run this some elements are changed to the color name and some aren't, also could a switch be better for this, if so how?

```
colors = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];  

function randomColor() {  //fills the array with a number from 1 - 16
  for (let i of colors) {
    colors[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*15+1);
    if (colors[i] === 1) {
    colors[i] = "red";
    }   
    else if (colors[i] === 2){
        colors[i] = "blue";}
    else if (colors[i] === 3){
        colors[i] = "yellow";}
    else if (colors[i] === 4){
        colors[i] = "orange";}
    else if (colors[i] === 5){
        colors[i] = "purple";}
    else if (colors[i] === 6){
        colors[i] = "pink";}
    else if (colors[i] === 7){
        colors[i] = "green";}
    else if (colors[i] === 8){
        colors[i] = "gray";}
    else if (colors[i] === 9){
        colors[i] = "black";}
    else if (colors[i] === 10){
        colors[i] = "white";}
    else if (colors[i] === 11){
        colors[i] = "darkblue";}
    else if (colors[i] === 12){
        colors[i] = "darkgreen";}
    else if (colors[i] === 13){
        colors[i] = "darkyellow";}
    else if (colors[i] === 14){
        colors[i] = "darkpurple";}
    else if (colors[i] === 15){
        colors[i] = "lightgreen";}
    else if (colors[i] === 16){
        colors[i] = "lightblue";}
    else { colors[i] === "clear";}
  }
    colors[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*15+1);

    return colors;
}


randomColors();
```

Comment: Below answer look good. I am just wondering when you were planning on updating ```colors[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*15+1);``` to be a colour? Looks like your code never attempts to change that to a color. When coming up with a solution, try to consider things like that.

Answer (score 1):

A `for...of` loop will loop through the elements in your array, *not* the indexes. You're treating `i` as an index rather than an element. Instead, you can change your `for...of` loop to be a regular `for` loop so that you loop through the indexes of your array:

```js
function randomColor(colors) { //fills the array with a number from 1 - 16
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { // loop through colors array
    if (colors[i] === 1) {
      colors[i] = "red";
    } else if (colors[i] === 2) {
      colors[i] = "blue";
    } else if (colors[i] === 3) {
      colors[i] = "yellow";
    } else if (colors[i] === 4) {
      colors[i] = "orange";
    } else if (colors[i] === 5) {
      colors[i] = "purple";
    } else if (colors[i] === 6) {
      colors[i] = "pink";
    } else if (colors[i] === 7) {
      colors[i] = "green";
    } else if (colors[i] === 8) {
      colors[i] = "gray";
    } else if (colors[i] === 9) {
      colors[i] = "black";
    } else if (colors[i] === 10) {
      colors[i] = "white";
    } else if (colors[i] === 11) {
      colors[i] = "darkblue";
    } else if (colors[i] === 12) {
      colors[i] = "darkgreen";
    } else if (colors[i] === 13) {
      colors[i] = "darkyellow";
    } else if (colors[i] === 14) {
      colors[i] = "darkpurple";
    } else if (colors[i] === 15) {
      colors[i] = "lightgreen";
    } else if (colors[i] === 16) {
      colors[i] = "lightblue";
    } else {
      colors[i] === "clear";
    }
  }
  return colors;
}

const colors = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
console.log(randomColor(colors));
```

Your code can be improved by also using an array to keep a mapping of each number to a color. This way, you won't need to use such a large if-statement:

```js
function randomColor(colors) { 
  const mapping = ["red","blue","yellow","orange","purple","pink","green","gray","black","white","darkblue","darkgreen","darkyellow","darkpurple","lightgreen","lightblue"];
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    const current_color = colors[i];
    colors[i] = mapping[current_color-1] || "clear";
  }

  return colors;
}

const colors = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
console.log(randomColor(colors));
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed a loop to continuously update them, implemented this into what I was doing and it is now working.

Comment: @DrewSandler no worries